# Determinant and Volume

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, volume

I recently encountered the following problem:

> Let $M$ be the finite set of 4 by 4 matrices $A$ with entries $a_{ij} \in \{1,-1\}$. Restrict the determinant viewed as a function on this set $M$ as follows: $$ det: M \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}. $$
>
> Find $A \in M$ so that $det(A)$ is maximal.

My idea is to view the determinant of $A$ as the volume of the parallelotope in four dimensions. Say we have the four vectors $a, b, c $ and $d$ (for example $a = \sum_{i=1}^4a_ie_i$), each of which specifies a different side of the parallelotope, then the determinant would be 
$$ det A= \sum_{\sigma\in S_4}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^4a_{\sigma(i),i}=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4
\end{vmatrix}
 $$
with every entry taking on the value 1 or -1. Viewing the determinant as a function, I would like to take its derivative and compute the entry values for which it gets a maximal value. I'm not sure how to approach this though.

Does anybody have any tips? :)

Comment: See if you can make the 4 vectors mutually perpendicular.

Comment: @fredgoodman I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Figure it out for the $2\times 2$ case and then the $3\times 3$ case.

Comment: @DougM For these cases I know easy formulas for computing the determinant. In the $4x4$ case I could choose the Laplace expansion and do the same thing, I guess.

Comment: @JtSpKg I was thinking more along the lines, of what is the pattern, that appears in the simpler cases, and how would you extend it to the $4\times 4$ case.  fredgoodman's strategy is sound.  If you can find 2 vectors that are perpendicular and have elements in $\{-1,1\}$ then find a 3rd that is perpendicular to that, and then a 4th.

Comment: @DougM Alright, so I get the vectors $(1, 1,1,1), (-1,-1,1,1),(1,-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1,-1)$

Comment: @JtSpKg great, and each vector has length 2, and they are all perpendicular then the volume of the parallelipieped that they form has volume $2^4$  Or you can calculate the minors, which is actually not all that hard.

Comment: I’m doubt that taking derivatives is the way to go since the elements of the matrices can only take on a finite set of values. Even if the elements could range over the entire interval $[-1,1]$, you’d still have to check the value of the determinant on the boundaries of the region $[-1,1]^{16}$ separately. That said, the partial derivatives are easy to compute since the determinant is linear in each of the matrix elements separately.

Comment: @DougM Thanks a lot for guiding me through it :) it's much easier than the approach that I tried to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known as [Hadamard's maximal determinant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem), for $n=4$ the maximum value is equal to $16$.